# How can i forbid a line break of a post in a 3-column layout?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

PARENT:

```
.footer {
    width:98%;
    height:98%;
    padding:1%;
    background-color:red;
    font-size:14px;
    column-width:50%;
    -moz-column-width: 50%;
    -webkit-column-width: 50%;
    column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    background-color:#2c2c2c;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Child:

```
.posting {
    border:1px solid grey;
    background-color:#585858;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}
```

Thats the HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="text">
            <div class="posting">
              CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class .postings contains one post, which is wrapped at the end of the column, I would like to prevent this, so that is a post always appears only contiguous.

Comment: You could try the CSS property white-space: nowrap, but it would definitely be better having your posting outside the div styled with columns

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in your CSS for your `.posting` class.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J4qrN/